# Questions about validation loss in deep learning

Tags: neural-networks

1. I believe the formula for calculating validation loss is $J=\frac{1}{N}\sum^N_i f(\hat y_i, y_i)$ where $N$ is the number of the data and $f$ is the loss function. However, some people calculate validation loss as $J=\frac{1}{M}\sum f(\hat y, y)$ where $M$ is the number of an epoch. What is the difference between them?
2. Let's say we compare two models for the same task (e.g. hyperparameter search). The first model which has a smaller batch size than the other will get small validation loss because of the second formula. Then how do I compare the different models with different batch sizes? Should I use different metrics such as F1 score or accuracy rather than validation loss?

Comment: So for the first epoch $M$ is 1, and the second epoch $M$ is 2, etc? This doesn't make sense because the same total loss would inevitably decline as $M$ increases. Where did you find this expression for loss?

Comment: @Sycorax https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/hyperparameter_tuning_tutorial.html#full-training-function

Comment: `val_loss/val_steps` is just an average over validation minibatches, not epochs. It’s proportional to an average over samples. They probably wrote it this way for simplicity’s sake, nothing else. The easiest way to compare the two models with different batch sizes is to compute the average loss over samples, using your first expression.

Comment: Okay. Now I understand. Thank you.

Comment: Feel free to write up your understanding as an answer. This will help future readers and let you gain twice the points.

Comment: @Sycorax Absoultey. I'm just working on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `sum(val_losses)/num_examples` in a epoch to get validation loss. This way makes me compare models which have different batch sizes. Then, we can compare models in terms of loss per example manner.